# Asp Mvc 6 Model Validation with a service in custom ValidationAttribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, data-annotations, dnx

TLDR: In Asp Mvc 6 how do I perform model validation with a service using data annotations? What are the alternatives?

I have a very simple model

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a service that exposes some simple validation methods

```
public interface IMyService
{
    string[] ReservedWords { get; }

    bool IsValidName(string name);

    // Internally calls IsValidName and throws an Exception if the name is invalid
    void Save(MyModel myModel);

    // ... snip
}
```

And I have wired up my controller like so

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMyService _service;

    public MyController(IMyService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    // ... snip

    public IActionResult Post(MyModel myModel)
    {
        if (!_service.IsValidName(input?.Name))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(MyModel.Name), "Invalid Name");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(myModel);
        }

        _service.Save(myModel);

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
}
```

It feels a bit clucky to have 2 stages of validation - automatic model validation then manually performing service validation. I was hoping that something simialr to this would work

```
public class MyModel
{
    [ServiceValidation(nameof(IMyService), nameof(IMyService.IsValidName)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public ServiceValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly Type _interfaceOrClass;
    private readonly string _methodOrProperty;

    public ServiceValidationAttribute(Type interfaceOrClass, string methodOrProperty)
    {
        _interfaceOrClass = interfaceOrClass;
        _methodOrProperty = methodOrProperty;
    }

    public override bool RequiresValidationContext => true;

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var service = validationContext.GetService(_interfaceOrClass);

        // Extension method in shared library to assist with reflection
        bool isValid = _interfaceOrClass.ValueForMethodOrPropertyNamed<bool>(service, _methodOrProperty, value);

        return isValid
            ? ValidationResult.Success
            : new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

However `var serivce` is always null, is there any way around this? I have wired up the `IMyService` to an implementation in the `Startup.cs` as it is available in the Controller.

**Alternatively** is there a better way of adding to the ModelState with a service?

Comment: Just wanted to comment that I have been working on this. I have not succeeded yet. Maybe I've got more time this weekend. The container in ValidationContext is acting very strange (from my perspective). But perhaps it's all logical when we figure this out.